# git push error: unable to write file ./objects/... No such file or directory

Tags: git

Trying to push but get this error, not sure what changed...

```
git.exe push --progress "origin" master:master

Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 552 bytes | 184.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to write file ./objects/07/c3e17df982d08b9963a67257103d959fc0acee: No such file or directory
error: unable to write file ./objects/f4/7e11c4ed46accda3120ff781a84b0ce5380ec0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of `git status`? Do the two files exist in your working directory?

Comment: @LinFelix Those files seem to be from the object database in the repository: `.git/objects/`

Comment: You are using git.exe therefore we are on Windows. May be a virus scanner has interfered and deleted the object files?

Comment: LinFelix..  yes, navigating to that directory I can see the files there, but they cannot be copied to the remote directory.  I know now why and it is related to what Robert says.  I was using Windows "Offline folders" that was blocking the copy.  I disabled that and now Git push is working.  Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems particularly weird because those errors:

- come out *after* the `Writing objects:` message, and
- are *not* prefixed with `remote:`, so seem to be coming from your own Git

and at this point your own Git should not be writing new objects.

In any case, it seems likely that something on your own computer is removing directories even though your Git is trying to use them.  That could happen if, e.g., you're running Git inside a dropbox folder, or other folder managed by some software that makes changes while Git is running.  (The thing to do in that particular case is "don't do that": Git needs, desperately, to have full control over the `.git` directory.)

Comment: I disabled Windows "Offline folders" that controls the remote repository directory.  Now I can again run GIT push.  Like you say... Git needs to have control over the .git directory. Thanks for the helpful comment.